# Unable to update data in table while using Apache camel and JPA with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, apache-camel

I am trying to consume message from table Example  and trying to update the status of selected data in repository but data is not getting save in Table Example  . Can anyone help me in this, is there any configuration is missing ?

My Routing Configuration is :

```
from("jpa://com.example.JPACamelBoot.entity.Example?consumer.namedQuery=selectQuery&consumer.delay=10000&consumeDelete=false")
        .process(myProcessor);
```

My Entity file is :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="EXAMPLE") 
@NamedQuery(name="selectQuery", query="SELECT e FROM Example e where e.status=2")
public class Example implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


@Id
@Column(name="NAME")
private String name;

@Column(name="AGE")
private Integer age;

@Column(name="LOCATION")
private String location;

@Column(name="STATUS")
private Integer status;
```

In MyProcessor.java I am performing update function as mentioned below :

```
@Autowired
    private ExampleRepository exampleRepository;


public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

    try {
    Message in = exchange.getIn();

    Example example=in.getBody(Example.class);
    Example exm= null;

    exm=exampleRepository.findById(example.getName()).orElse(null);

    exm.setStatus(1);

    Example  exam =exampleRepository.save(exm);

   System.out.println(exam.getStatus());
```

As in named query I am using "SELECT e FROM Example e where e.status=2 "
When I am printing 
 System.out.println(exam.getStatus()); // output 1 but the same is not getting update in database .

I am using apache camel 2.22.0 and Spring boot 2.0.4.RELEASE .

Comment: Can you turn on logging of SQL statements and post what you see. logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG

Comment: org.hibernate.SQL: select example0_.name as name1_0_, example0_.age as age2_0_, example0_.location as location3_0_, example0_.status as status4_0_ from example example0_ where example0_.status=2
org.hibernate.SQL: select name from example where name =? for update
org.hibernate.SQL: select example0_.name as name1_0_0_, example0_.age as age2_0_0_, example0_.location as location3_0_0_, example0_.status as status4_0_0_ from example example0_ where example0_.name=?
org.hibernate.SQL: update example set age=?, location=?, status=? where name=?

Comment: what happens if you use saveAndFlush instead of save?

Comment: When I am calling controller class from main method and then same repository.save() my data is getting save in database but when I am using Apache camel and then trying to perform update or insert activity , it is not happening . Anyway with saveAndFlush also no luck in my case .

Comment: Can anyone help in this regard .